# Trouble With a Step in an Infopath - SPD 2010 Workflow

Tags: infopath, designer-workflow

I hope I can explain this clearly. I have created an InfoPath form linked to a SPD 2010 workflow. My workflow is repeating **ONE** step over and over (repeating an email function).

Step 3 functionally triggers a command only when “RevRec Approved” in my InfoPath form equals YES – this triggers an email… this works fine. The email trigger in Step 3 – alerts via email that an action must now be completed.

***Problem**:* Upon completion of my action on the InfoPath form (which is triggered by clicking "Click Here to Save and Complete" the workflow is repeating Step 3 over and over by resending the email alert rather than going to Step #4.

I’ve tried to include several actions after the "email trigger in my SPD workflow" such as stop workflow, pause for duration etc… however it still repeats the same email over and over.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: was not allowed to add image...? prompt said I needed at least (10 reputations)?

Comment: Welcome to SP-SE. You are correct in that brand new accounts are not allowed to post pictures until they have received 10 reputation points, but you're already only 4 points away! You could try to answer a different user's question to make up the difference, because I think pictures of your configuration would add value in describing your problem.

Comment: You may also want to read over the FAQ to familiarize yourself with the site - http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: Since now you have earned enough reputation, you can attach an image!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're constantly updating the list item (check version number) and each update triggers the same workflow on it.

You should probably add another field in the form's main data source to store a boolean value "already sent" and check its value (should not be true) before sending the email and setting its value to true right after sending the email.